# Hyperlink in Streamlit dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hyperlink, streamlit

I am attempting to display a clickable hyperlink inside a dataframe containing filtered results on Streamlit. This is my code so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

df = pd.read_excel(

  io='list.xlsx',
  engine= 'openpyxl',
 ).fillna('')

def make_clickable(link):
    # target _blank to open new window
    # extract clickable text to display for your link
    text = link.split('=')[0]
    return f'<a target="_blank" href="{link}">{text}</a>'

# TRAILER is the column with hyperlinks
df['TRAILER'] = df['TRAILER'].apply(make_clickable)

df['TRAILER'] = HTML(display(df.to_html(render_links=True, escape=False), raw=True))
```

If I use:

```
df['TRAILER'] = df['TRAILER'].apply(make_clickable)
```

I get

```
<a target="_blank" href="{link}">{text}</a>
```

displayed as a string but not a hyperlink.

When I add:

```
df['TRAILER'] = HTML(display(df.to_html(render_links=True, escape=False), raw=True))
```

I get:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

displayed as a string but not a hyperlink.

These are the versions I am using.  Other components of the site work only with a lower version of Streamlit which is why I am using this version.

```
streamlit == 0.83 numpy == 1.18 pandas == 1.2 openpyxl ipython == 7.22 python == 3.9
```

[image: site screenshot]

I cannot use     `st.markdown`     or     `st.write`     directly as I am using     `st.dataframe`     to display the results.

Comment: I think this can help [Display URLs in dataframe column as a clickable hyperlink](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/display-urls-in-dataframe-column-as-a-clickable-hyperlink/743). Also please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `st.write(df.to_html(escape=False, index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

df = pd.read_excel(
  io='list.xlsx',
  engine= 'openpyxl',
 ).fillna('')

def make_clickable(link):
    # target _blank to open new window
    # extract clickable text to display for your link
    text = link.split('=')[0]
    return f'<a target="_blank" href="{link}">{text}</a>'

# TRAILER is the column with hyperlinks
df['TRAILER'] = df['TRAILER'].apply(make_clickable)

st.write(df.to_html(escape=False, index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

---

On a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

link1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641666/hyperlink-in-streamlit-dataframe"
link2 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731937/how-to-plot-comparison-in-streamlit-dynamically-with-multiselect"
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "url": [
            f'<a target="_blank" href="{link1}">Hyperlink in Streamlit dataframe</a>',
            f'<a target="_blank" href="{link2}">How to plot comparison in Streamlit dynamically with multiselect?</a>'
        ],
        "label": ["question", "question"]
    }
)

st.write(df.to_html(escape=False, index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

It gives:

[image: Hyperlinks to SO questions (dataframe)]

Comment: I cant use st.write or st.markdown as it wont show the final spreadsheet with the filtered results.  I have already tried this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @PhilippGärtner This will likely be [implemented](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/983#issuecomment-1238484061) in streamlit in 2023

Comment: you will lose all other built-in features (etc. sort and search).

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now available directly in `streamlit` via the `LinkColumn`  (see [doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.column_config/st.column_config.linkcolumn) for more details) configuration.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"name": "Google", "url": "http://google.com"},
        {
            "name": "Streamlit Link Column",
            "url": "https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.column_config/st.column_config.linkcolumn",
        },
    ]
)

st.header("DataFrame")
st.dataframe(
    df,
    column_config={"url": st.column_config.LinkColumn("URL to website")},
)
```

[image: Example Screenshot]